# Создать отскок элемента

Tags: c#

Нужно чтобы `label` отскакивал от стенок формы (не вылезая за неё) при каждом тике таймера, при этом меняя цвет при ударе о стенку. Очень срочно нужна помощь новичку-студенту.

```
public partial class TextRun : Form
{
    Color[] Rainbow =

{
     Color.Red,
     Color.Orange,
     Color.Yellow,
     Color.Green,
     Color.Aqua,
     Color.Navy,
     Color.Purple
     };

   // Timer timer = new Timer();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    public TextRun()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //инициализирует все компоненты, расположенные на форме: поля, кнопки, меню, 
        //переключатели и т. п.

    }

       static int Time = 0; //создаём счётчик

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Time++; //увеличиваем его на 1 с каждым "тиком" таймера 
        TextRun Run = new TextRun();
        x = Run.ClientSize.Width;
        y = Run.ClientSize.Height;
        w = labelGo.Size.Width;
        z = labelGo.Size.Height;
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sin(30));
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Cos(30));
        i = labelGo.Location.X;
        j = labelGo.Location.Y;

        //labelGo.Text = Convert.ToString(Time);
        //Color Rain;

       // Rainbow = new Rainbow();

        //labelGo.ForeColor = ColorConverter.Rainbow();

    }

    private void TextRun_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void ButtonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        labelGo.Visible = true;
        ButtonGo.Visible = false;
        ButtonGo.Click += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);

    }
}
```

Comment: Я полностью не вижу условий сравнения с границами рамки, по которой должен прыгать ваш лэйбл, ну и вам пригодится знать ширину и высоту текста в пикселях, вам поможет textrender.

Ещё не понял создание класса в вашего текстранера при каждом лике таймера, это зачем?

Comment: `Math.Sin()` и `.Cos()` принимают аргумент в радианах, на заметку. А преобразование в целое выглядит крайне подозрительно. Да и в целом неясно, зачем всё это нужно.